# SQL query modification to include a condition as part of difference between timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as the following which works:-

```
select a.account_id AS ACCOUNT_ID, a.customer__id AS CUS_ID, b.first_Name AS NAME,
b.last_time - a.last_time AS LAST_TIME_DIFFERENCE
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.account_id = b.account_id AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (a.last_time - b.last_time)) > 6
ORDER BY b.first_name
```

last_time is a column of type timestamp. I am looking to add an if/else such that if the difference between (a.last_time - b.last_time) in days is 0, only then I'll have to add the EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (a.last_time - b.last_time)) > 6 condition to the "AND" clause (as part of WHERE). How can I modify this query to include that logic?

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle. Please tag only one database.

Comment: The logic you describe seems to comes down to: there should at least a 6 hour difference between the two dates. So why not just: `a.last_time > b.last_time + interval '6' hour`?

Comment: @GMB yes but only if its on the same day, does this account for same day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT a.account_id,
       a.customer__id AS CUS_ID,
       b.first_Name AS NAME,
       b.last_time - a.last_time AS LAST_TIME_DIFFERENCE
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND a.last_time    > b.last_time + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
ORDER BY b.first_name
```

(Which works whether the `last_time` columns are dates or timestamps.)

or, if the `last_time` columns are timestamps:

```sql
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND a.last_time - b.last_time > INTERVAL '6' HOUR
```

or, if the `last_time` columns are `DATE`s (which, in Oracle, always have a time component):

```sql
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND a.last_time - b.last_time > 6/24
```

or, you can ensure the `DATE` difference is evaluated as a interval using:

```sql
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND (a.last_time - b.last_time) DAY TO SECOND > INTERVAL '6' HOUR
```

---

#### Update:

If you want the timestamps to be on the same day then:

```sql
SELECT a.account_id,
       a.customer__id AS CUS_ID,
       b.first_Name AS NAME,
       b.last_time - a.last_time AS LAST_TIME_DIFFERENCE
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND a.last_time    > b.last_time + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
          AND a.last_time    < TRUNC(b.last_time) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER BY b.first_name
```

or:

```sql
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON     a.account_id   = b.account_id
          AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id
          AND a.last_time - b.last_time > 6/24
          AND a.last_time < TRUNC(b.last_time) + 1
```

Comment: I'd want to use the logic a.last_time - b.last_time > 6 only if both timestamps are on the same day. How did you account for this in the code?

Comment: @Ash Updated to check they are on the same day.

Comment: @MTO was trying to understand how a.last_time > b.last_time + INTERVAL '6' HOUR works, would this return true whether or not a and b were timestamps on same day or different day? Also what does AND a.last_time    < TRUNC(b.last_time) + INTERVAL '1' DAY imply?

Comment: @Ash You end up with `b.last_time + INTERVAL '6' HOUR < a.last_time AND a.last_time < TRUNC(b.last_time) + INTERVAL '1' DAY`. `TRUNC(b.last_time)` will truncate the time component to midnight on the same day and then when you add 1 day you get midnight of the next day; therefore `a.last_time` is between 6 hours after `b.last_time` and midnight of the day after `b.last_time` so, yes, if you combine the two filters it will restrict `a.last_time` to be the same day as `b.last_time`.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of trick which you can utilize using `decode` operation.

```
select a.account_id AS ACCOUNT_ID, a.customer__id AS CUS_ID, b.first_Name AS NAME,
 b.last_time - a.last_time AS LAST_TIME_DIFFERENCE 
from tableA a, tableB b 
where 
  a.account_id = b.account_id 
  AND a.customer__id = b.customer__id 
  AND decode(floor(abs(a.last_time - b.last_time)),0,abs(a.last_time - b.last_time)*24,2) > decode(floor(abs(a.last_time - b.last_time)),0,6,1)
ORDER BY b.first_name
```

Comment: why did you include floor as part of decode?

Comment: conditon to check difference on same day can give in decimal values like 0.25...floor gives  you least round value as 0 says no difference on days.